# How to hide legend for the size and normalise size by area in VegaLite?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

The legend for sizes is shown on the right side, how to hide it completely?

Second question - it seems like the circle diameter are proportional to the given number. How can I scale it in another way, so that:

- The biggest circle would have the size of 10px
- All the smaller circles will be smaller **proportionate to the area**, not diameter. And not smaller than 1px.

The [live playground](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhOtRpEqpAMKQA0VdUARmQEycMAXw5daXBmRbtB1SL1QB2WWBErxdSU1aiuPMgBYVasSsyMoAERl79qAIzHd1DXIuRrzzQrACuJuld6d08zO18AOkd-LxowrSsbPXl+CIBmJ3V4kKSJHwA2TNNbBMgAUVzvMgAOKKLA7KkK2PofIxiskvdm+J9lf0EAXSoAyEIAOwBjAHtoAEtxgHMyDUhiOYAvQhWVBgAPOdJUIMx4OfhcbdQAMzxiQnq5a7nCXGgpXkEAzD2diVgDkc0PEzhcrmBbrh7o96M9Xu8mLwWpB4ABPAAO4MgAEd8LBxqCEHMsNsvl5IKi-poAYcqRJQZcyJDoR0JHC3lIkMi0ZipONpgBbBZ4SBfEa6SAC2AAJwA1lJJnNpZNGSAhEA).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the legend completely, use `"legend": null` within the encoding in question (see the [Legend docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/legend.html)).

To control the range of sizes, you can use the `scale.range` setting. For example, `"scale": {"range":[0, 50]}`, will make the size of points vary between 0 and 50 pixels (see the [Scale.range docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#range)).

Here is an example of both being used in your example chart ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJEqpAMKQA0UARmQEwC+LV1WvSjM2kTqgDsfARiFkmrDmQAsM6jToKAIkvFkAjOo3yGusRLC9+GtFrN7LXAHRGbJ+1HPLULgMzGgp6Q3vqoAGyBcsEAoo5kAByuUZrCkHEWqil2aRk+YNKyALpUxpCEAHYAxgD20ACWFQDmZOgYkMT1AF6ErbKYAGb1hLjQCpzu1JDwAJ4ADr0MAI74sBXw9YgbWL2T7cRVeIt2AE5rTcfkAAxsAKxXRdmQuIQXFWOoFfi4uLJRkAAPVp0AH1UioWgbeAvMhfH58KBDEYfZRiWYLBQrNZQhD1HaQf4zYGwUHguxQmGfb64BGQJGjBRINHzY6QCo1AC2jTwBNK7kgHNgJwA1goqvUTlUYSAeEA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "C", "b": 2},
      {"a": "C", "b": 7},
      {"a": "C", "b": 4},
      {"a": "D", "b": 1},
      {"a": "D", "b": 2},
      {"a": "D", "b": 2.1},
      {"a": "D", "b": 2.3},
      {"a": "D", "b": 6},
      {"a": "E", "b": 8.1},
      {"a": "E", "b": 4},
      {"a": "E", "b": 7}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "size": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"range": [0, 50]},
      "legend": null
    },
    "x": {"axis": {"title": null}, "field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"axis": {"title": null}, "field": "a", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "mark": "circle"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It seems like it's by default works as expected and make sizes of circles proportional to its areas.

Comment: How to use the json spec itself (in observablehq for example) or how to use legend=null in the js style spec specification? i.e. vl.data(...).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a custom size you might need to put the empty legend definition inside of encoding / color to hide it:

```
"encoding": {
    ...
    "color": {
        ...
        "legend": null
    }
}
```